# How to ignore empty NullFields when collecting to list with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have theses two tables

```
+---------+--------+ author_df
|AUTHOR_ID| NAME   |     
+---------+--------+
|  102    |Camus   |
|  103    |Hugo    |

+---------+-------- +------------  book_df
|AUTHOR_ID| BOOK_ID + BOOK_NAME  |     
+---------+-------- + -----------|
|  1      |Camus    | Etranger
|  1      |Hugo     | Mesirable  |
```

I did some `join` and `aggregations` as the following

```
result_df = author_df.join(book_df, 'AUTHOR_ID', 'left')\
        .groupby('AUTHOR_ID', 'NAME')\
        .agg(f.collect_list(f.struct('BOOK_ID', 'BOOK_NAME')).alias('BOOK_LIST'))
```

And I get a dataframe with this structure

```
root
 |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer
 |-- NAME: string 
 |-- BOOK_LIST: array 
 |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer 
 |    |-- BOOK_NAME: string
```

the problem is when I want to write the `result_dataframe` to json I get empty objects `{}` in the list, like

```
{
 ...
 "BOOK_LIST": [
   {}
 ]
}
```

Even when I tried the option `ignoreNullFields`

```
  result_df\
     .coalesce(1)\
     .write\
     .mode("overwrite")\
     .option("ignoreNullFields", "true")\     # this option
     .format("json")\
     .save(path)
```

But I get some empty objects that I want to remove

````
```JSON
{
 ...
 "BOOK_LIST": [
   {
     "BOOK_ID": null,
     "BOOK_NAME": null
   }
 ]
}
````

````
In the resulted dataframe `result_df.show(truncate=False)`
```S
+---------+-----------------+ 
|         | BOOKS_LIST      |     
+---------+-----------------+
|         |[{null, null}]   |
````

So how to remove the object with null values and get emplty array instead ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply we need just to add a condition `f.when().otherwise()` to our collect list, for our case

```
 .agg(
      f.collect_list(
          f.when(f.col("BOOK_ID").isNotNull(), f.struct('BOOK_ID', 'BOOK_NAME')).otherwise(f.lit(None))).alias("BOOK_LIST")
      ),
```